# SQLite table without Primary Key but Why generate record for each update

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I create a SQlite Table without primary key using Class as follow. But Each time I update, SQLite keeps generating record for each update. It should override the same record which it was first created but should not generate record for each update.

Thanks.

```
Not adding this to the class:   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]

class NetworkCredential
 {

        public string WebServiceName { get; set; }

        public string WebServer { get; set; }

        public int Port { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; } 

        public int DefaultCredential { get; set; }

    }


 using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
 {
    var User = db.Query("Select * From NetworkCredential").FirstOrDefault();

    if (User != null)
    {
        User.WebServiceName = txtWebServer.Text.Trim();
        User.WebServer = txtWebServer.Text.Trim();
        User.Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);

        int success = db.InsertOrReplace(User);    
    }
   else
    {
        int success = db.Insert(new NavNetworkCredential()
          {
             WebServer = txtWebServer.Text.Trim(),
             WebServiceName = txtWebServiceName.Text.Trim(),
             Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text)

            });
  }
```

Comment: er,  "same record" means that each record has some sort of identifying attribute; some distingushed lookup column that means you/the database knows which "row" belongs to which record.  you need a column to serve as some kind of "primary key" you might say.

Comment: I need some verification. Understand that Class without [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement], this will store only ONE record. Each time I update, it should used the same record. Am I doing it right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "same record"?

Comment: Say, 1st time I create a record : WebserviceName ="DynAX", WebServer="192.168.x.x" Port ="8080". The next time, I pull the record out using Above Logic FirstOrDefault(), this same record, I make an update by changing Port="7030". But in my case, SQLite generate a new record. so in total I have 2 records instead of one.